# Solr default site search doesn't have article excerpt or does it

Tags: solr

I was wondering if there was more documentation on the easy site search index from Solr 5+?

If you `$ bin/post -c site https://siteurl.com -recursive 2 -delay 1` it will index your site automatically. The issue here is there is not a simple article excerpt for displaying out. I would think this would be at least the basic default of a search display. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpts are usually generated by [using the Highlighting functionality in Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting) at query time.

That way the excerpt is extracted around the terms that matched your query.

Depending on your field names, the highlighter is activated by setting `hl=true&hl.fl=fieldname`.

Comment: I am using the default crawl of a site by doing: ($ bin/post -c site https://siteurl.com -recursive 2 -delay 1) which I can only assume that it won't have an excerpt in the default. Is there a way to turn on Highlighting or add to this method?

Comment: @Anthony This is done query time, not when indexing. Highlighting should be available in most (all) Solr installations.

Comment: I can go to the query and select the highlight (hl) checkbox. There must be something missing in the doc where it will store an excerpt in this basic search. I don't see any text for the page being searched by this basic search function but it does store something as you can search for items, not in the query *:* return and it will find the right page.